# plotting multiple function on octave. I already looked for an answer but something is not working

Tags: plot, octave, piecewise

Let f be a continuous real function defined on the interval [a,b]. I want to aproximate this function by a piecewise quadratic polynomial. I already created a matrix that summarizes these polynomials. Let's say that I'm considering a uniform partition of the interval into N pieces ( therefore N+1 points).

I have a matrix A of size N times 3, where the k row represents the quadratic polynomial associated with the k-interval of this partition in the natural form ( the row [a b c] represents the polynomial a+bx+cx^2). I already created a method to find this matrix (obviously it depends on the choice of my interpolation points inside of each interval but that it doesn't matter for this question).

I'm trying to plot the corresponding function but I'm having some problems. I used the same idea given in [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955950/how-to-implement-a-piecewise-function-and-then-plot-it-on-certain-intervals-in-m?noredirect=1&lq=1). This is what I wrote

```
x=zeros(N+1,1);
%this is the set of points defining the uniform partition
for i=1:N+1
 x(i)=a+(i-1)*((b-a)/(N));

end
%this is the length of my linspace for plotting the functions
l=100
```

And now I plot the functions:

```
figure;
hold on;
%first the original function
u=linspace(a,b,l*N);
v=arrayfun( f , u);
plot(u,v,'b')

% this is for plotting the other functions
for k=1:N
  x0=linspace(x(k),x(k+1));
  y0=arrayfun(@(t) [1,t,t^2]*A(k,:)',x0);
  plot(x0, y0, 'r');
end
```

The problem is that the for is plotting the same function f and I don't know why. I tried with multiple different functions. I'm pretty sure that my matrix A is correct.

Comment: Have you tried to put `hold off` at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Please write a minimal working example that can be run as standalone code or copy/pasted from people here to check where you might have a bug -- often in the process of reducing your code to its bare principles in this manner, you end up figuring out what is the problem yourself in the first place. But, in any case, I have written one myself and cannot replicate the problem.

```
figure;
hold on;

# arbitrary values for Minimal Working Example
N = 10;
x = [10:10:110];   # (N+1, 1)
A = randn( N, 3 ); # (3  , N)
a = 100; b = 200; l = 3;
f = @(t) t.^2 .* sin(t);

%first the original function
u = linspace(a,b,l*N);
v = arrayfun( f , u);
plot(u,v,'b')

for k = 1 : N
  x0 = linspace( x(k), x(k+1) )
  y0 = arrayfun( @(t) ([1, t, t.^2]) * (A(k, :).'), x0 )
  x0, y0
  plot(x0, y0, 'r');
endfor

hold off;
```

Output:

[image]

Are you doing something different?